# Homology of the Empty set

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am under the impression that the standard convention for the homology (singular) of the empty set is 0 in all non negative degrees and $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree $-1$. I have no problem with this convention, I am just curious what role it plays. Most conventions helps something sensible remain true in a particular case, what is this convention doing?

Doe this convention depend on which version of cohomology we use? Is there a different convention for Cech or what have cohomology?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an idea. The *reduced homology*  of the empty set is what you describe: one $\mathbb Z$ in degree $-1$ and $0$ otherwise. This is because the chain complex computing the reduced homology groups has an extra $\mathbb Z$ in degree $-1$, whose role is to kill one $\mathbb Z$ in degree $0$. However, if we are looking at the empty set, all chain groups are $0$ so there is only the extra $\mathbb Z$ in degree $-1$. I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Hatcher says "we had better require X to be nonempty" when he defines reduced homology in order to avoid this very issue

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I think of it.

With simplicial homology, we start by considering the set of all continuous maps from the $n$-simplex into our space $X$, $\{\sigma:\Delta^n\to X\mid\sigma\text{ continuous}\}$. Then we form chains of these by taking the free abelian group $C_n:=\mathbb{Z}\{C_n(X)\}$. These are the terms of our chain complex along with the boundary maps.

But what about for $n<0$? Hmm... that doesn't seem to make sense here so I guess let's just say that $C_n(X)=0$ for $n<0$. **But wait!** What about $n=-1$?

The $n$-simplex is the convex hull of $n+1$ (affinely independent) points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ so the $(-1)$-simplex is the convex hull of 0 points, i.e. the empty set. So $\Delta^{-1}=\varnothing$. Thus, $\{\sigma:\Delta^{-1}\to X\mid \sigma\text{ continuous}\}=\{\text{the empty function}\}=\{\varnothing\}$. Then $C_{-1}(X)=\mathbb{Z}\{\{\varnothing\}\}\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

This is where the extra $\mathbb{Z}$ in dimension $-1$ really comes from for reduced homology. However, for $n<-1$ the definition of simplex really *doesn't* make sense, so we'd better keep those terms of the chain complex zeros.

Poor guy.. Everybody always forgets about the empty set, and especially his alias "the empty function" :(

**TLDR**: The definition of a simplex means that the empty set is a $(-1)$ dimensional simplex

Comment: This question was asked 10 years ago, so you should keep in mind that this question might not be relevant anymore to OP.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur one really special role that MSE plays in the mathematics community is as a repository for knowledge that is often "well-known" but not actually written down anywhere. No reason to not provide more knowledge for posterity.