# Hatcher 2.2 Exercise 33

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The following is a question from Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology":

> Let $X$ be a space such that $X$ is the union of $n$ open sets $A_i$ with the property that every intersection $A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_k}$ is either empty or has trivial reduced homology. Show that $\tilde H_p(X)=0$ for $p\geq n-1$. Give an example for each $n$ that shows this is the best possible bound.

I had no trouble proving the first statement with a little induction and an easy application of the Mayer Vietoris sequence. I am having a great deal of trouble thinking of an example that shows it is the best bound possible, however

For each $n$, I must find a space $X$ which can be decomposed into $n$ open sets such that all possible intersections of these sets are either empty or have trivial reduced homology. In particular, these open sets must themselves have trivial reduced homology, if I am understanding the question correctly. Furthermore, I must have $H_{n-2}(X)\neq 0$.

I am having trouble even coming up with a space that has trivial reduced homology in all dimensions. I was thinking that $\mathbb{RP}^n$ might work somehow with its decomposition into copies of projective spaces of lower dimension, but these aren't open sets.

Any hints?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the boundary of an $(n-1)$-simplex, which is homeomorphic to $S^{n-2}$. It has $n$ $n-2$-dimensional faces. Let your open sets be small open neighborhoods of these faces. Then the nonempty intersections will be neighborhoods of smaller dimensional faces, and will be contractible.

Comment: Ha, I feel silly for not thinking about making my pieces contractible. Thanks!

Comment: Why does Hatcher say "every intersection $A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_k}$ is either empty or has trivial reduced homology"? Isn't the reduced homology groups of the empty set already trivial?

Comment: It's not usual to talk about reduced homology of the empty set, but if you were to talk about it, you would get an unwanted $\mathbb Z$ in degree $-1$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I see. So, for example let's say we have $X=A_1 \cup A_2$. If $A_1 \cap A_2 = \varnothing$, is $\tilde{H}_0(A_1 \cap A_2) =0$?

Comment: @aljebr Yes, but $\widetilde{H}_{-1}(\emptyset)=\mathbb Z.$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15254/homology-of-the-empty-set

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I'm just not seeing how homology in $-1$ dimension applies to the problem. Is it necessary for this problem? Just wondering why Hatcher writes that statement in the problem.

Comment: @aljebr It means that the reduced homology of the empty set is *not* trivial.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Not trivial only dimension $-1$?

Comment: @user46372819 Correct. $\tilde{H}_i(\emptyset)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $i=-1$ and $0$ for $i \not= -1$.